# How To Programmatically Locate 'default.realm' File In An iOS App

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Realm has now removed the `defaultPath` property from the `Realm` object. I am using this property in my code, and it is now being flagged as an error saying that the property does not exist. Is there another way to programmatically locate my app's `default.realm` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Realm's various configuration options have been grouped together as  `Realm.Configuration`. The default configuration is accessible as `Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration`, and its path is available via the `path` property.

Comment: Thank you. It appears that it was moved instead. It also appears that it is user configurable. I was wondering if this was possible. I am working on a way to explicitly backup the default.realm file in case the user of my app has to change devices or upgrades to a new device.

Answer (score 0):

In **Realm 0.9x** - `path` property has been changed to `fileURL`

You can find `default.realm` file location programmatically by using the below code.

```
 let realmFilePath = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL
 print("Realm File Path",realmFilePath!)
```

[image: file Path]